# How to read the Excel file through Azure data factory for limited columns data but number of rows are uncertain

Tags: excel, azure-data-factory

Using Azure data factory, I am trying to read the excel file for the column  A to F but number of rows are changing every time. Please help me to define the range dynamically.

**Working case** : If I give the column range as A1:F9999 it is reading the data specified range.

**Not working case:** If I give as A1: ( as suggested by microsoft doc) to read all the column and rows from excel, it is not working throwing a below error

*"Invalid excel cell range 'A1:' with error 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'.
Index was outside the bounds of the array."*

Please help me with any leads

Regards,
Rajesh K

Comment: Hey, It should be just A1 and not A1:

Answer (score 1):

Thank You `@Nandan` for your suggestion- We have tested in our environment;

Give only **`A1`** in range it scans a table beginning with the specified cell `A1`, dynamically detecting all the rows below it and all the columns to the right of it.

**If you want specific range of columns, you must have to mention that.**

***Output***

[image]

**Kindly refer below Microsoft document links for more understanding**

[Mapping data flow Debug Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-debug-mode?tabs=data-factory)

[Excel file format in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel)